# How to get return (status) value of an external command in Vim

Tags: linux, shell, vim

I want to get the exit value (returned by `$?` on a shell; usually 0 or 1 for success or failure) of a external shell command in Vim. Note that I want to get its standard output too. So I can use the output and the also the exit value in a Vim conditional expression. Is this possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is `v:shell_error` variable that has exactly the same value as `$?` in shell scripts. Works at least after `:!`, `:read !`, calling `system()`.

Answer (score -4):

its like this

var=$(echo $?)

will give you the value of $? into the variable var.
The standard output of course is obtained. because, only after the output is worked, the return value is obtained. ($? comes either as 0 or 1 only after executing the command).

Comment: This answer is for bash, not vim.